# Symfony getting data from Java web service

Tags: symfony-2.4

I would like to create a project that will use Java web service instead of the Symfony ORM. I would like to know if this solution is possible.

Like I get the information in JSON and after transform this information in a Symfony object to use it easily in the twig template and every where else.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's possible...

Take a look at [Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle) and at [how to make it a bundle](https://renoirboulanger.com/blog/2012/07/how-i-managed-to-make-work-guzzle-rest-client-library-under-symfony-2-0-x-as-a-bundle-snipet/). The tutorial is a bit outdated since you're using Symfony 2.4 but it should work out.

Of course you can always use [file_get_contents()](https://www.php.net/file_get_contents) and the like or [cURL](https://www.php.net/curl) to fetch information from the Java web service.